# Matlab - winopen Error

Tags: matlab

I tend to use the winopen function alot, to open files with their default program, or folder location with windows explorer.

I've recently replaced my PC with a laptop (both were 64bit), and all of the sudden, winopen doesn't work anymore, and throws the exepction:
The file name association is incomplete or invalid.

It's important to emphasize that my code hasn't changed, and it's worked before.
Also, when trying a Matlab example: winopen(which('meshgrid')), the function works (I think the main problem may be when trying to open a folder).

Please help :)

Comment: The error is likely a Windows one, not MATLAB; Windows cannot determine which application to use to open the desired file. Useful information to include in your question is *what* file/folder is causing the error.

Comment: Try:
 winopen(pwd)
Get:
Error using win_open_mex
The file name association is incomplete or invalid.

Error in winopen (line 60)
win_open_mex(pathstr, filename);

Comment: See [this MATLAB central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/310516).

Comment: Seen it already. No help there :)

Comment: You already contacted technical support?